# Error when interconnecting ipcRenderer and ipcMain in electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, electron, angular-cli

I have configured cli angular in electron, and I have a link where it execute a function that intercomunicate ipcRenderer and ipcMain:

html:

```
<a (click)="check()"> click </a>
```

component:

```
constructor(private _e: ElectronService) { }

check () {
   this._e.ipcRenderer.send ('conn', 'round');
   this._e.ipcRenderer.on ('conn-st', (event, args) => {
      console.log (args);
   });
}
```

main.js (electron):

```
ipcMain.on ('conn', function (event, args) {
  event.sender.send ('conn-st', 'trip');
});
```

The problem is that when you click once, you do it once, but when you click again it does 3, then 4, 5 and so on continuously.

And throws this error upon reaching 11:

```
(node:23006) Error: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 conn-st listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

How do I end the connection between ipcRenderer and ipcMain?

Comment: There actually is no "connection", like UNIX sockets, Electron will emit a signal to all listeners which then trigger the defined function. The error message appears to only say that there were 11 listeners created, which all listen to the same "socket".

Comment: And how do I restart that listeners?

Comment: "Restart" is maybe the wrong word, because it means they would keep listening after that. But every listener (as created) with `ipcRenderer.on();` creates a unique id and can be removed with `ipcRenderer.removeListener(channel, listener);`. But please refer to the [Electron doc](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/ipc-renderer/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping more about electron, i solved it with this:

    this._e.ipcRenderer.send ('conn', 'test');
    
    this._e.ipcRenderer.on ('conn-st', (event, args) => {
        console.log (args);
        this._e.ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners ('conn-st');
    });

Comment: You are very welcome. Should I create an answer so that you can accept it?

Comment: Yes, that's right, you should create it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That error message only says, that 11 listeners to a "socket" (like the ones in UNIX) were created. Every listener creates a unique ID which is returned when creating the listener. Based on that, removing one particular listener could be done like this:

```
// Create a listener.
var myListener = function (event, args) {} 
ipcRenderer.on("channel", myListener);

// Delete only this one by its ID:
ipcRenderer.removeListener("channel", myListener);
```

But you can also delete all of the listeners that were created for a socket, like this:

```
// Create a few listeners.
var myListener0 = function (event, args) {};
var myListener1 = function (event, args) {};
var myListener2 = function (event, args) {};
var myListener3 = function (event, args) {};

//
ipcRenderer.on("channel", myListener0);
ipcRenderer.on("channel", myListener1);
ipcRenderer.on("channel", myListener2);
ipcRenderer.on("channel", myListener3);

// Delete all listeners for socket "channel".
ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners("channel");
```

This is also covered in the Electron documentation, particularly [here](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/ipc-renderer/).

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is nolonger correct as per the electron documentation [documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendererremovelistenerchannel-listener). The listener is a function and should be removed as shown below.

```
// Create a listener
let listener = (event, args) => {}
ipcRenderer.on("channel", listener );

//Delete the listener
ipcRenderer.removeListener("parse-cm-request", listener);
```

Comment: Please edit the accepted answer to reflect the changes